# query regarding using smtp for a contact form

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to ask a developer that cannot I use smtp.lib to make a contact form work in main.py

I tried using smtp service , took the data from the html form and pass it through smtp and send me that email. but when I launch the website and try to send me the email , there come error 502 server cannot handle this request , so the thing I want to ask how do I make it work if i cannot use it with main.py code, is there some rule or something because of what it is not working cause when I run the code in the development server in my pc it works but when I launch the website it doesn't work.
This is the code:
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 text-center my-3">
                            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-a button-big button-rouded">Send Message</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
```

main.py:

```
@app.route('/blogs', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def blog():

    id = request.args.get('id')
    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.form.get("username")
        email = request.form.get("email_id")
        website = request.form.get("website")
        message = request.form.get("message")
        if not website:
            website = "not available"
        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
            connection.starttls()
            connection.login(MY_EMAIL, MY_PASSWORD)
            connection.sendmail(
                from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
                to_addrs=MY_EMAIL,

                msg=f"Subject:This is the feed back you got from a user!\n\nHis name is:{name}\n "
                    f"His email is {email}\n"
                    f"His website is {website}\n"
                    f"And he wants to say to you that:{message}"
            )

  

    return render_template("blog-single.html", id=int(id))
```